# Google Street View in an Appcelerator MapView

Tags: iphone, google-maps, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Using Appcelerator Titanium Mobile to build an iPhone app, is it possible to enable Google street view within a mapview?  If so, how?

Comment: Yes, it works in a webview, and that looks like what I'm going to end up doing given lxt's answer below.  What I meant was: Is it possible to do it in a mapview? I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: what about half/half, only opening the streetview in webview and the rest in mapview you would obviously need the links too. If you are going to do a webview you may find this helpful https://gist.github.com/853084 since you can take over controll of all links

Comment: I won't be doing the half/half thing because most of the positives I expected to get by doing a mapview are not materializing.  But it's a good suggestion!  Meanwhile, that code snippet (to change links in a webview to events only) may come in handy, so thank you for that as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Street view isn't part of the standard iOS native APIs, so whatever framework you use you won't be able to integrate it into a native app: sorry!

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, obviously, but it's the answer I needed to hear.  Thanks.